# What are the easiest tools to use to make a search-engine?

Tags: indexing, web-crawler, search-engine, facet

I want to build a search engine that will crawl a website, say [recipe.com](http://www.recipe.com), or a site that lists products or services of some sort, index the relevant information and then be able to perform faceted search.

I tried using Nutch and Solr, but I got stuck on indexing only the relevant information instead of the whole webpage and indexing it in fields. I'm now trying to use a [Nutch plugin](http://www.atlantbh.com/precise-data-extraction-with-apache-nutch/) to parse the html pages, but I'm no good at web stuff and I'm wondering if there's and easier way.

I'm not looking for an optimal solution.

Answer (score 1):

Scrapy a python tool would help with crawling and scraping. You can scrape the products to a json structure, and then index in elasticsearch. 
Most of OSS tools  require you to get your hands dirty (i.e programming).

P.S: You need more than search : Please edit title "What are the easiest tools crawl, scrape, index, and search".

Answer (score -1):

Windows already has the search engine built in. From NT4 to WinXP there was Indexing Service, from WinXP to Win8 there’s Windows Desktop Search, and they all can be configured to index arbitrary content including remote site. All you have to do is configure the source, ensure the indexing is complete, and then use query engine to search.

Or, MSSQL server has the full-text search built-in since version 2005. Since MSSQL 2008, there’s HTML filter already built-in.

Or if you don’t like Windows, there’re plenty of third-party solutions available, both free and commercial. [Here’s the comparison.](http://wrg.upf.edu/WRG/dctos/Middleton-Baeza.pdf) I don’t have experience with any of them, so can’t recommend any.